# Regarding number of thread showing in jmeter result

Tags: jmeter

**scenario** : there is  some pages [ example  home ,about us ,contact us etc]  , but to visit those pages user have to first login to the system and if user enter wrong username and password then system will thorow alert. so test this condition i have used the csv config so that i can test this scenario for more than 1 user lets say 4. in the user details csv i have listed 4 users credentials [ ie username ,password] out of which 1 credential is wrong. i deliberately put the wrong credential to verify weather system is returning proper alert or not.

my test case like -

test case - 
      thread group [ i added csv config directly uder the thread group  + aggregate report listner ] -----

```
            login controller -  http login sampler [ i added assertion under login sampler and 2 listerns under login sampler , view result tree , assertion result] + 

            browse controller - http about us sampler-[ i added 1 listerns under login sampler , view result tree ]
```

After running the test case

In the thread group i have set no of thread=4 and run the test case.

i found that system has detected the wrong username +password  attempt by indicating it in the red colour in the view result tree listner which was under the login sampler.but in the result tree of about us listner number of thread is showing 4 and also in the aggregate controller  in the http about us sampler page no of thread is showing 4

**so what i want to know that . out of the 4 threads one thread has already stopped in the login page because its credentials was wrong and without login one can not proceed to inner pages like about us ,contact us etc,then why 4 threads are showing in the about us sampler  view result tree and in aggregate result . it should show 3 as 3 threads provided the valid credentials to proceed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the *action to be taken after a Sampler error* in the Thread Group options.
Default is continue, give it a try with **Stop Thread**.

Comment: Thank carlo , it working correctly now.i have put stop thread now its showing 3 in the inner pages which is correct. i have 2 more questions similar to my previous question.1 in those user group 2 have the permission to view the about us page and one dont have the permission to view about us page

Comment: for the person who do not have the permission to view any perticular page  then on clicking that page from the top  navigational bar system will redirect to home page by default.but in the view result tree listner of about us page no of user should show 2  as 2 persion can proceed to about us page and in the aggregate result also 2 thread should show in the no of thread column of about us page sampler  but it is showing 3 .can you suggest what should i do , i also want add one point here that system is using ajax and json .

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this one, I suggest you to ask another question with this new problem.